# How to dynamically change images in map reports?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layouts, reports

I need to make a report about several cadastral parcels which data are contained inside three different tables of a database. Report must contain:

1. Cadastral data taken from the three tables
2. A photograph of the front of the building (these photos are .JPG images contained in a folder)
3. View of the cadastral cartography over the ortophoto centered in the cadastral parcel

In order to make these reports, I have created one template in the QGIS map composer. To obtain the reports easily and fast, I though to program in PyQGIS a script that change the strings, the images and the view of the template depending the cadastral reference.

I found how to change the map view and the strings, but I don't know how to change the photos of the buildings. These photos have the format "CADASTRAL REFERENCE".jpg, so, knowing the cadastral reference is easy to find the right photo in the folder.

Comment: To be clear, the photos are in no way linked to the GIS data, they just happen to have a filename that matches? I'm thinking this might be easier if (or perhaps even require) the images to be attachments to the parcels - ie a linked attribute. But even if they were I don't know the details of how to do it, just a thought of something to investigate.

Comment: Hello Chris. As you know, when you insert an image in the QGIS map composer this one, in the beginning, is empy. Then, in the propierties you set the path of the image you want to add. Then... It is possible to change this path in PyQGIS? Or there's another way to get what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Why not data define the image path? Next to the image filename is a button which allows you to link the path to an attribute in your data (or set via an expression).

Comment: @cartocarlos This is what I was getting at. I'm not familiar enough with QGIS to know the details, but if the image path is a property of the parcel data then it can be referenced just like the parcel itself in your report. If there's no link between the data and the images other than the images have a filename that contains a string/value in the data, then you have to go some long way around of extracting that string/value and accessing folders and files to look for a match. Instead just store the path as an attribute, if not the image itself as an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "dynamic" images in your report, you need to data define them.  This is how it is done.

1. Prerequisite: You have one or more attributes in you report layer that can be used to generate the image file names (this is Cartocarlos' situation).
2. Add an image (*Add Item-> Add Image*) to the body of the group that shall contain the "dynamic" image.
3. Make sure that the image is selected on the canvas, go to the *Item properties* on the right, and find *Image source* in the *Main Properties* section.
4. Click on the data defined override button of *Image source* (small button to the right, labelled with an epsilon) and choose *Edit...*

   [image: data define picture]
5. In the expression dialogue, enter an expression that returns the absolute file system path to the "dynamic" image.

   `concat(@project_folder, '/img/', "cadastral", '.png')`

   Here it is assumed that:

   - The location of the image directory (*img*) is given relative to the location of the project/QGS/QGZ file (using `@project_folder`)
   - That the report layer has an attribute `cadastral` that identifies the image
   - That the images are PNGs with suffix 'png'

   Check that the *Output preview* shows the absolute path of one of the images, as shown in the screenshot below:
   [image: Expression dialogue]

And that should be it.

Comment: Thanks at all. Although I made the question five years ago, your answer helped me last week.